# Change endpoint route on environment stage

Tags: c#, url-routing, razor-pages, environment, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a test page which should only be available in development stage. At the moment the page will just redirect, when the environment is not set to development.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    if (_environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        await GetTestData();

        return Page();
    }

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

But I do not really like this approach. Is there a way to catch this on the endpoint level itself? Like a fallback?

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Registration");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a lot of different ways of solving this issue. However, I would use Feature Management from Microsoft - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/use-feature-flags-dotnet-core?tabs=core5x.

You can put your page/feature disable by default on appsettings.json, and then override this value on appsettings.Development.json to enable it.

This also gives you the flexibility of enabling features for only a X amount of people.